# Apt "Connection failed"

Tags: networking, apt

Since installing Ubuntu I have been unable to install new packages, it has even failed to update. Below is a dump of connection error I see when I tried to install Wine:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unixodbc/odbcinst1debian2_2.3.1-4.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/fonts-wqy-microhei/ttf-wqy-microhei_0.2.0-beta-2_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Please try running `sudo apt update` and then try your original command again. Also, is your internet connection working normally?

Answer (score 2):

The issue definitely related with connectivity, try to ping or trace ubuntu servers. If connectivity is fine, probably you are behind proxy, use environment variable:

```
export http_proxy=<your_proxy>:<port>
```