# install and update

Tags: 18.04, updates

when the ubuntu 18.04 LTS is connected to my home wifi modem it keeps bringing up this error when it tries to update or install a software(I'm sure that the computer has the access to the internet because the browser is working)

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease           
Err:2 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
   Connection failed [IP: 185.142.156.14 80]
Err:3 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
   Connection failed [IP: 185.142.156.14 80]
Err:4 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
   Connection failed [IP: 185.142.156.14 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 185.142.156.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 185.142.156.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 185.142.156.14 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

but when I use my mobile hotspot it's totally ok.
what's the problem?

Comment: Hi majid and wellcome to AskUbuntu.
Can you open this site with your browser: http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/ with your WLan and your Hotspot?

Comment: Seems like you proved conclusively that your network, not Ubuntu, is the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apt "Connection failed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907859/apt-connection-failed)

Comment: Hi Boba, no I can not open it with any of them, apparently now even with the Hotspot I get the same error!